# Failure in loding rJava library in R on MacOs

Tags: java, r, rjava

After updating the new MacOs, the system add a new preferred shell zsh., if you have a problem of the shell like reminding you to switch bush or zsh in beginning of terminal, please referring to https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/4/18651872/apple-macos-catalina-zsh-bash-shell-replacement-features

For rJava error which I countered after updating system, many people have this same problem like

```
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
     .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
      call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
      error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
      dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
      Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
      Reason: image not found
```

and it couldn't run `sudo R CMD javareconf` to reset the path.

Comment: https://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/

Answer (score 0):

This topic has already been discussed at (https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2254) and the basic approach to solving this problem is at (https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rJava/)

However this post is little bit old and inapplicable for the new mac system.

Personally, you need to install the "Homebrew" function at terminal with

```
    ~$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)
```

The next step need you to install brew and gcc, but remember you need to install gcc 7.2.0. to do this you need to type this in terminal

```
~$ brew install gcc@7
```

and rename the motherfolder to gcc, and change the inner folder name to 7.2.0  so the pathway should be `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc' (Command+Shift+Dot to show hidden folder)

You need to install the Java SE Development Kit 11.0.1 to fit rJava. link is (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html) search 11.0.1 in the page and you can download it, no specific requirement for Java you can download the updated one here (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)

After you installed the java you can start from step4 for the instruction (https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rJava/) and after you do all the thing remember to run `sudo R CMD javareconf` to reconfigure the R